# How can I send data updates to Meteor server from a desktop application?

Tags: meteor

I'm just getting into using Meteor, and yesterday I managed to get a leaflet map running with custom tiles. My goal is to get player positional data from a game and send it to a Meteor server to distribute to other players viewing the map in real time.

The data is available to a small desktop application on the player's machine and Meteor can easily handle the distribution part, so all I'm missing is getting the desktop application to talk to the Meteor server. What would be the best way to go about this? Is there a way to get Meteor to listen for incoming data from an external source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can communicate directly with a meteor server using its native Distributed Data Protocol (DDP). You can find the specification document [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/livedata/DDP.md), and an up-to-date node driver [here](https://github.com/oortcloud/node-ddp-client). Some searching may turn up implementations in other languages.

Alternatively, you could use [server-side-routing](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#server-side-routing) in iron router to allow clients to use HTTP to POST/PUT their positions. The drawback of this solution is that you may need to come up with some way for clients to uniquely identify themselves (e.g. using a unique key) so you don't get bogus data.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks! Didn't really realize I could just use DDP like that. Falling more and more in love with Meteor every day. =D